# I was wondering how I could find the inductor mean current?

Tags: power-electronics

If I know the peak to peak value of inductor current, is there a way I could find the average of that current from just knowing the peak to peak ripple?

Comment: You talk about two different measurements at two different places in your question. If you know the Peak to peak value of the inductor current you just average them. But if you only know the peak-to-peak ripple then there's nothing you can do since you do not know the DC-bias that offsets the ripple.

Comment: Okay assuming i have a rectifier circuit, I’ve found the angle at which discontinuous mode of conduction for inductor begins, inductor acting as a smoother, and discontinuity came about because I decreased load current, so now I have a higher load voltage, how do I find the average inductor current now? I was thinking integrating the peak voltage subtracted from the load voltage over angle of continuity to angle of discontinuity and dividing by inductance but that just gives ripple i guess.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

If all you know about a waveform is its peak-peak amplitude, no, that's not enough to determine its mean.

If you know the wave-shape of a periodic signal with period \$T\$, then in general you can the mean from

$$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}x(t)dt.$$

If the wave-shape is known to be a triangle wave (for example, in the inductor of a buck regulator), then the mean value is simply the average of the minimum and maximum values the signal takes in each cycle. But that's a special case that you could work out by using the integral formula.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0NHcEzM , this is what I’m talking about. here, it states that the mean load current can be gotten from the angle beta when I = 0, basically when discontinuity occurs and from the load voltage, I don’t get that part.

Comment: @Kwaku, it would help to know what circuit you are asking about (with a schematic). If you know the wave shape you can use the integral formula to get the mean. If the circuit is a full-wave or half-wave rectifier followed by an LC filter, then you could calculate this, for example.

Comment: yeah a 3 phase diode bridge rectifier circuit, discontinuous mode. I’m just confused as to what the limits should be.  https://imgur.com/a/piFqkLM

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney, the limits can be any ones that span a period of the waveform.